# Does Azure Function Kafka Trigger Supports OAuth Authentication Mechanism?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-functions

We are using Azure Function with Kafka Trigger as below:enter image description here
[image]
Now, we wanted to use OAuth for this. as we have "ClientId", "Client Secrete", "Scope" and "Token URL" to pass here

Answer (score 0):

The extension currently only [supports the listed the authentication methods](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-kafka-extension#connecting-to-a-secure-kafka-broker)

- SASL/PLAIN
- SASL/SCRAM
- SSL/TLS

There is an [open issue that tracks the addition of the SASL/OAUTHBEARER method to the extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-kafka-extension/issues/427).